# Calculate statistics for certain areas of a raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, clip, zonal-statistics, masking

I want to calculate the value of certain areas of my raster, which are determined by a polygon layer. I can't use the zonal statistics tool, I receive an error about inputs. How should I do it?(the green spots is my polygon layer)
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? Zonal statistics is the correct tool for this. You could try converting your polygons to a raster layer and using that as the Zone layer.

Comment: @DanC I think the problem was my raster, having float values instead of integer. I went back and made my raster again and used the tool, it worked out. thanks

Comment: @AmirarsalanRajabi Please consider adding your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try using Zonal Statistics as Table. It will calculate the statistics (many options, such as area, mean, median, min, max, etc.) of the raster within your polygons or another raster layer.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was my raster, having float values instead of integer. I went back and made my raster with integer values again and used the tool, it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

In Mapinfo you can do this easily.

Below steps should work if you have Mapinfo 15.2 and above (64 bit version).

1st way is to create a polygon on top of your raster and run region stats tool. Under Raster TAB-> Operations-> Region Stats. This will give you stats of the area on which polygon is created.
[image: Image showing Region Stats tool in Mapinfo 16 64 bit]

2nd way is to clip the raster using clip tool and then open statistics tool.

[image: Shows Clip Tool and Statistics tool]

Let me know if you run into some trouble.